# Recommend a optimization book with more coding examples?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I am interested in continuous optimization problems.

However, I feel it is very difficult for me to understand the classic books such as [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) or [Numerical Optmization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387303030). My problem with these books are they are too mathematical and lack of examples in "code form". After using some tricks to transform a problem into convex problem, then done.

Could anyone recommend some books with more labs like [modern optimization with r](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319082622). (My problem with this book is it is too practical and lack of depth.)

PS. for discrete optimization, the [coursear course](https://www.coursera.org/course/optimization) is great. I spent countless hours on the homework and climb up the leaderboard. But looking for a one with continuous optimization.

Also, I am not against math at all and know math is the necessary to understand the content. But I do have more engineering mind and want to try many things to enhance the understanding.